# gRPC Python - how to add idle time for client

Tags: python, grpc

I'm using gRPC to call a service in client. After I set up channel:

```
    channel = grpc.insecure_channel('server_url:service_port')
    stub = Client.Stub(channel)
```

It works pretty good. However, if there's 5 minutes not using the client to send request, then the next request will get error message:

```
grpc._channel._Rendezvous: <_Rendezvous of RPC that terminated with (StatusCode.UNKNOWN, Stream removed)>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the gRPC retries functionality when the channel breaks is still work in progress and not fully available yet.  One thing you could do as a workaround is to write an interceptor to retry automatically if it sees such error.

Comment: I've tried this method if connection timeout then retry until succeed, but not work well. can you show me an example? Tnx

Comment: @JieHu It looks like there might be a bug in gRPC itself https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/9779 https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/15623

Comment: Yes, and it's still there, so I have to use a keepAlive heatbeat to keep the gRPC connection alive.