# How to set RetryPolicy when calling _publisherClient.PublishAsync via grpc c# client (for PubSub)

Tags: c#, grpc, google-cloud-pubsub

We are publishing messages 1 by 1 to google pubsub service to a given topic using c# with Google.Cloud.PubSub.V1 nuget
Every few minutes we receive error message

```
Grpc.Core.RpcException: Status(StatusCode=Unknown, Detail="Stream removed")
```

Do I need to set

> RetryPolicy

To fix this? (I saw on [github issue python1](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/issues/4826), [python 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50689396/grpc-python-how-to-add-idle-time-for-client) & [github issue C#](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/15623#issuecomment-491017247) that manually doing client retry didn't fix this) So;
How to set RetryPolicy when calling _publisherClient.PublishAsync via grpc c# client (for PubSub)

Otherwise should this issue be fixed by enabling

```
new ChannelOption("grpc.keepalive_permit_without_calls", 1)
```

What is the meaning of "Stream removed" error?

RpcException - [Status Codes](https://grpc.github.io/grpc/csharp/api/Grpc.Core.StatusCode.html) (error codes)

Comment: The only way I handle this currently is by having a retry in client code; retrying 4 times with 10 seconds delay; still it could fail which means to either further increase the delay btw retries or do more tries..
Which I do not think is a nice approach..

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45257255/set-keepalive-for-grpc-in-c-sharp-client

Answer (score 1):

The client libraries generally abstract users away from these lower-level concerns.

I agree with you that the C# library should itself be re-establishing streams and retrying publishes as needed. If publishers are not behaving as expected or you think there are properties that should be set on the underlying connections, please put in an issue at https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-dotnet/issues

Answer (score 1):

This is due to a bug during client library generation, which causes the retry configuration to not be applied.
Issue filed here to fix it: https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-dotnet/issues/5225

Update: This is now fixed in github (https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-dotnet/pull/5226) and is expected to be released next week (week of 2020-08-03).

Comment: how to configure retry attempts and call timeouts in the new package (Google.Cloud.PubSub.V1.2.1.0)?